# node is appended after base url and before actual link

Tags: routes, navigation

I am using drupal 7
In my home page when i hover any link say node/45 then there is right link like base_url/node/45

> But after visiting any node i.e. when i go to node/45 page, on that page when i hover on any link then node is prepended 
>   For ex: when i hover on products link then base_url/node/products is coming, i mean node/ is append before path.

Comment: So, just to clarify, it's linking to something like a: http://node/yoursite.com/45 instead of http://yoursite.com/node/45? Or b: http://yoursite.com/node/term/path/45 instead of http://yoursite.com/term/path/node/45? Are you using Pathauto or other path aliasing?

Comment: like option **B** and i am using pathauto module

Comment: Does it happe on all paths? What do your pathauto settings look like?

Comment: thanks beth, there was configuration problem in pathauto settings, and it got fixed :-)